# What does my Samsung Galaxy 5 consider an App?

Tags: applications, updates, samsung-galaxy-s-5

After a recent phone update (which took too long due to "too many apps") I saw the total apps updated was over 700.  I only have 69 apps on my phone.  Why the discrepancy?  What does my android phone consider an "app"?  Can I delete these others?

Comment: Possibly system apps. Also: many components that are part of the system, but are only libraries (JAR files in the system) need optimization as well and are considered "apps" for that procedure.

Answer (score 0):

69 normally visible apps don't account for all the system apps/packages/functions.

If you run an app like CCleaner you can easily see, using the app manager section, what all the apps on your phone are. Most of them will be locked and you can not remove them, as without root you can't generally touch system apps.

Comment: But 700 seems way too high. You've not addressed that part.

Comment: 700 would be high if it were just standard launchable applications, but I don't think it is too high if it is including packages/services etc.

But yes, I agree. If it isn't count those as such, 700 is outrageous.